# Modulating a json key

Tags: javascript, json

i'm right now working with a cocktail API and fetch data out of json.
My question is:

Is there a way to rename a json key for example it's original is "strIngredient1" and I want it to be just "strIngredient", so that I can count up to the last key with the same name but changing last number.
My idea was to include all objects into one string without doing "ingr1" + "ingr2" + "ingr3" and so on:

var x = 1;

var ingr = data.drinks[0].strIngredient+x;

var ListIngr = "";

do{

x++;

ListIngr.innerHTML =+ `${ingr}`

while(ingr != null);

I already searched a lot, but couldn't really find anything.I'm still new to working with Json.

[image: JSON of the API]

Comment: (1) Don't post text as image. Type the text (and format with selcet+toolbar button), and (2) provide the desired result for that specific input. (3) read the usage description of the `json` tag -- it doesn't belong here.

Comment: That console output is showing an object, its properties/keys and its values. Use that to google for an answer, because JSON is a text format and unrelated to your question. (and do not use w3schools to learn JS...)

Comment: It's not clear what you wanna do, but you surely can't have two or more keys with the same name in a json file or a JS Object for obvious reasons... If you want to select all keys starting with a certain pattern use a RegExp: `Object.keys(JsonObject).filter(k => /^strIngredient/.test(k))` or something like this.

Comment: Also please state what the actual goal is here. It shouldn't be necessary to mess with the keys, what is the [actual problem](https://xyproblem.info/) you're trying to solve? One way: https://jsfiddle.net/ht53xb2m/

Comment: @ChriG, that's what I was searching for. 
Sorry for making it that hard to get what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: No problem, the key is that instead of `data.abc + x` you need `data["abc" + x ]`

Comment: Duplicate: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)